# intent startActivityForResult returned result but the program crashed

Tags: android, android-intent

ok the parent activity call BuyActivity using startActivityForResult and return 3 values to the parent activity. One of them is category. There are 3 categories food, personal and education that can be chose. I got no problem when i choose education or personal but i get this error when i choose food but the parent activity still received all the 3 values returned. So anyone can help?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {apps.project/apps.project.ConsultExpert}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

this function call the startActivityForResult

```
 private void displayBuyQuestionnaire() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BuyActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, BUY_ADVICE); 
}
```

inside BuyActivity.class

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("item_name", iName);
            returnIntent.putExtra("item_price", iPrice);
            returnIntent.putExtra("item_category", iCategory);
            setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent); 
            finish();
```

onActivityResult

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    switch(requestCode) {
    case BUDGET_ADVICE: 
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data.hasExtra("status")) {
            item_name = data.getStringExtra("status");
            Log.d("return", data.getStringExtra("status"));
            runBudgetTree();
        }
        else {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                Log.d("msg", "result code ok tp x semua return");
        }
            break;

    case BUY_ADVICE:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           item_name = data.getStringExtra("item_name");           
           item_category = data.getStringExtra("item_category");
           item_price = data.getDoubleExtra("item_price", 0);
           runBuyTree();
        }

        break;
    }
```

LogCat

> 01-09 17:56:51.776: D/var i(3159): answer1 01-09 17:56:51.776: D/var
>   i(3159): answer2 01-09 17:56:51.776: D/var i(3159): answer3 01-09
>   17:56:51.781: D/AndroidRuntime(3159): Shutting down VM 01-09
>   17:56:51.781: W/dalvikvm(3159): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578) 01-09 17:56:51.786:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3159): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 01-09 17:56:51.786:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3159): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering
>   result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has
>   extras) }} to activity {apps.project/apps.project.ConsultExpert}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 01-09 17:56:51.786:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3159):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2536)
>   01-09 17:56:51.786: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2578)
>   01-09 17:56:51.786: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117) 01-09
>   17:56:51.786: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:965)
>   01-09 17:56:51.786: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 01-09
>   17:56:51.786: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 01-09 17:56:51.786:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3159):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691) 01-09
>   17:56:51.786: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-09
>   17:56:51.786: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 01-09 17:56:51.786:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3159):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
>   01-09 17:56:51.786: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665) 01-09
>   17:56:51.786: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 01-09 17:56:51.786:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3159): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   01-09 17:56:51.786: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):   at
>   apps.project.ConsultExpert.runBuyTree(ConsultExpert.java:364) 01-09
>   17:56:51.786: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at
>   apps.project.ConsultExpert.onActivityResult(ConsultExpert.java:1769)
>   01-09 17:56:51.786: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):   at
>   android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3934) 01-09
>   17:56:51.786: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
>   01-09 17:56:51.786: E/AndroidRuntime(3159):   ... 11 more

Answer (score 1):

You have to place  displayBuyQuestionnaire() method line

```
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, BuyActivity.class);
```

by this

```
          Intent intent = new Intent(<your class name>.this, BuyActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thred is old but just for Future reference :

Same Problem took my 1 hrs so just sharing solution which worked for me. I was Trying to get message send from second activity in a `Textview` of First. `ResponseToFirst` is message id and `Message_fromsecond` is `textview`.

Earlier in `onActivityResult` i was using

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 Message_fromsecond.setText(extras.getString("ResponseToFirst")); //crashed here
```

Later i found that i need to use

```
String returnString = data.getExtras().getString("ResponseToFirst");
Message_fromsecond.setText(returnString);
```

For More info Have a look [Here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Overview_of_Android_Intents).